# Why can’t I find my Yoast sitemap in the root directory?

Tags: wordpress, xml-sitemap, yoast

I use Yoast on my WordPress website. When I visit `mysite.com/sitemap_index.xml`, I can see the sitemap but when I look in the root directory, there is no file as sitemap. I tried “show hidden files” on cPanel but that didn’t show me anything as well.

Comment: WordPress content is dynamically generated, and the same applies to Yoast sitemaps - they're dynamically created when requested, so you're not going to find a sitemap file in the root directory (see [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-does-yoast-create-the-sitmap-xml-files/)).